# NHibernate and Byte[] as Primary Key

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have only started experimenting with NHibernate and couldn't get my head around the following scenario, hope someone can shed some light on it. Thank you.

I want to refactor existing Data Access Layer from Subsonic to NHibernate. The existing database is using `BINARY(16)` as primary key. In Subsonic, it has no problem dealing with byte[] as primary key. In NHibernate if I attempt to map a property that has `byte[]` datatype, I'll come across the following exception messages:

```
{"Illegal use of an array as an identifier (arrays don't reimplement equals)."}
```

Example of my entity and mapping (with FluentNHibernate) as following:

```
    public class Product
    {
        public virtual byte[] Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

.

```
    public ProductMapping()
    {
        Table("tblProduct");
        Id(p => p.Id).Column("prdProductGuid");
        Map(p => p.Name).Column("prdName");
        Map(p => p.Description).Column("prdDescription");
    }
```

Is there a way to workaround this issue? Thank you.

Currently working with .NET 4.0, NHibernate 3.3.1 and MySQL 5.1.52.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a look of Hibernate community and found [a hint](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2186603#p2186603) on utilizing `IUserType`.

I've created a custom class **Bytes** that's essentially a serialized wrapper for bytes array:

```
[Serializable]
public class Bytes
{
    private byte[] _value;
    public byte[] Value { get { return _value; } }

    public Bytes(byte[] bytesValue)
    {
        _value = bytesValue;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) {...}
    public override int GetHashCode() {...}
    public override string ToString() {...}
}
```

**BytesUserType**:

```
public class BytesUserType : IUserType
{
    private static readonly NHibernate.SqlTypes.SqlType[] _sqlTypes = { NHibernateUtil.Binary.SqlType };
    public NHibernate.SqlTypes.SqlType[] SqlTypes { get { return _sqlTypes; } }
    public Type ReturnedType { get { return typeof(Bytes); } }
    public bool IsMutable { get { return false; } }

    public object NullSafeGet(IDataReader dr, string[] names, object owner)
    {
        object obj = NHibernateUtil.Binary.NullSafeGet(dr, names[0]);
        if (obj == null)
            return null;
        var value = (byte[])obj;
        return new Bytes(value);
    }

    public void NullSafeSet(IDbCommand cmd, object obj, int index)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            ((IDataParameter)cmd.Parameters[index]).Value = DBNull.Value;
        else
        {
            Bytes a = (Bytes)obj;
            byte[] valueBytes = a.Value;
            ((IDataParameter)cmd.Parameters[index]).Value = valueBytes;
        }
    }

    public new bool Equals(object x, object y) {...}
    public object DeepCopy(object value) {...}
    public int GetHashCode(object x) {...}
    public object Replace(object original, object target, object owner) {...}
    public object Assemble(object cached, object owner) {...}
    public object Disassemble(object value) {...}
}
```

Updated my entity and mappings:

```
public class Product
{
    public virtual Bytes Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
}
```

.

```
public ProductMapping()
{
    Table("tblProduct");
    Id(p => p.Id).Column("prdProductGuid").CustomType<BytesUserType>();
    Map(p => p.Name).Column("prdName");
    Map(p => p.Description).Column("prdDescription");
}
```

And that does the trick!

Comment: Yeah, that's also a valid solution. The Bytes class is what you would have had as a component class in my solution, but you wouldn't have needed the IUserType implementation.

Comment: I am just curious: please, have you tried to change the C# mapping from byte[] into GUID? I've tested that (on MS SQL server) and it is working. Just use the Binary(16) as a Guid. Just curious;)

Comment: @RadimKöhler Yes I have. I'm working on MySQL 5.1. Setting Identifier to `Guid` appears false positive, but with close examination with NHibernateProfiler you will see NHibernate treating the identifier as VARCHAR(32) and generates SQL something like: `WHERE prdProductGuid = '0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF'` instead of `WHERE prdProductGuid = 0x0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF`, which means you won't able to Get, Update and Delete.

Comment: Thanks for response. Interesting. (as I said, on MS SQL server it works correctly)

Comment: @rockacola Cloud you please update the implementation of equals ,GetHascode,DeepCopy,..and other methods in both Bytes and ByteUserType classes?

Answer (score 2):

I would say that it is much more easier than it could seem. 16 bytes, would most likely represent GUID (Unique-identifier). Which for ID makes more sense than weird and mysterious byte array...

Just change your C# class to have ID of a GUID type

```
public class Product
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
}
```

The rest will be done for us inside of the NHibernate.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a component as a composite key. The component would have only the byte[] as a property, but it would enable you to provide useful implementations of GetHashCode() and Equals().